# How can i list all transcation of bitcoin using API.. I need all transcations and current transactions of coin( e.g bitcoin)

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, currencies

How can i list all transaction of bitcoin using API.. I need all transactions and current transactions of coin( e.g bitcoin)
I need APIs that can give me all transaction related data of particular coin and all coins as well

Comment: Use Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we access all transactions, including spent transactions, through bitcoind?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13081/how-can-we-access-all-transactions-including-spent-transactions-through-bitcoi) and [Is it possible to download all blockchain raw data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53377/13866)