# How download whole blockchain and preprocess it for analysis?

Tags: blockchain, technical-analysis

Will be grateful for any information/starter points/tuts etc.

For ex. this question (answers don't contain any "real" answer, any url to "blockchain files", any suggestion where to find it and how to download).
[Is it possible to download all blockchain raw data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/is-it-possible-to-download-all-blockchain-raw-data)

my question is how to download blockchain in format which is will be accesible for understanding, processing, information extraction, etc.
Is it possible?

p.s
If you push downvote button at least explain why, please

Comment: You can download blockchain using a full node implementation like Bitcoin Core or Knots. Not sure what kind of analysis are you looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to download all blockchain raw data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/is-it-possible-to-download-all-blockchain-raw-data), there are also potentially useful answers to [similar questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=download+blockchain) which point to various repositories

Comment: @Prayank Thank you for knots looks like ideal wallet for me :) but actually I looking something more simple to understand I want to analyse dynamic of transactions if I understand correctly blockchain contains all id's and all transactions so in theory you can use it info to understand "something" about transactions (ex. how often on id make transaction per day, etc)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thank you for your comment. But your first url doesn't contain any url to blockchain. Ideally I want blockchain as document (not inside of a client) or something like that and simple way to open it and see blocks. I tried to find something similar in google and here but actually I didn't find any simple for my understanding how extract blockchain via some readable file :(

Comment: @tempdeltavalue: Don't think this should be downvoted but there is a replicate question and if the answer to that question isn't comprehensive enough the answer should be improved on that question or an additional answer should be added. Welcome to Bitcoin StackExchange though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the wrong place where to ask, but I know that also it is difficult to find a place where ask this question (maybe).

I would add an answer to this question because I made research in my bachelor's degree, where we analyze the bitcoin graph, but at the same time, I developed a way to make also a useful serialization of the blockchain with metadata for future research. The solution is called [SpyCBlock](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/SpyCblock) and a demo that works on the JSON data is described in the readme ([link](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/SpyCblock#-star-json-version-bitcoin-blockchain-octocat-)).

However, you need to download the bitcoin blockchain with bitcoin core and make the parsing of it with SpyCBlock, and maybe make this serialization available for the world?

It is the only software that I know that produces a serialization in JSON of the blockchain, but maybe there is something new around?

Comment: Yeap, you are right (Thank you for your answer). I'm also found some python solution 

https://github.com/citp/BlockSci

Comment: well it depends from what you are using, blocksci use a big machine to make the analysis, SpyCBlock use only a normal computer :) it ran also on Raspberry PI

Comment: yes, but for now I'm just downloading blockchain it takes some time :) Probably after that I'll try blocksci because I'm more familiar with python. But anyway will see, for now I'm not sure that exactly I want to :)

Answer (score 0):

We just published a paper that deals exactly with this question, I think. It presents a method and scripts to download the whole data **and add indexes that make it easy to use**. It also provides the dataset obtained on March 2021, that contains all data available in the blockchain at that time. Please see http://bitcoin.complexnetworks.fr/

Comment: I'm windows user so I cannot really test your thing (I heard about VirtualBox). Also you paper it's really long... But in general I "don't want" to work with parsed dataset, also I'm not sure if you have access to id's of wallets... In other world can your tool answer on question "How much traders we have in blockchain (some date) and how much transactions they do?" , if yes can share some specific place in your doc? (sorry to bother you)